# Getting specific list element from a series

Tags: python, pandas

I need to run a function that returns two different values for each row, and I did it with

```
result = df.apply(
    lambda row: pandas.Series(
        (do_something(row), do_something_else(row)),
        index=('result', 'meta')),
    axis=1)`
```

However, running this on a dataset that has 2.8mil rows quickly run into memory problem (and it is also much slower than returning just one column). I wonder if it is possible to do this

```
result = df.apply(
    lambda row: (do_something(row), do_something_else(row)),
    axis=1)
```

(a series with a tuple of two elements in each row), and have the possibility to access just the first (or the second) element for each row without going through `series.apply()` if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved the problem differently

after doing

```
result = df.apply(
    lambda row: (do_something(row), do_something_else(row)),
    axis=1)
```

instead of trying to break them into two individual series, I did this

```
new_result = pandas.DataFrame(
    result.values.tolist(),
    index=df.index,
    columns=('column1', 'column2'))
```

I actually break the original `df` into chunks to be multiprocess-able (with concurrent.futures), so the example actual call should look like this

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as pool:
    jobs = []

    for i in range(njobs * 10):
        bounds = (ceil(i * data.shape[0] / float(njobs * 10)),
                  ceil((i + 1) * data.shape[0] / float(njobs * 10)))

        jobs.append(pool.submit(
            df[bounds[0]:bounds[1]].apply,
            some_func_returning_tuple_of_two,
            axis=1))

    result = pandas.DataFrame(
        list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([job.result() for job in jobs])),
        index=data.index,
        columns=('result', 'meta') if has_meta else ('result'))
```